# How to calculate age from DatePicker?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to validate that the user is old enough to use my app (> 15). In my app, the user has to set his/her date of birth during the sign up. From that I want to calculate the age in order to check whether the user is old enough.

The XAML code:

```xml
<Label Text="Date Of Birth"/>
            <DatePicker BackgroundColor="White" Date="{Binding DateSelected}"/>
            <Label TextColor="Red" Text="You have to be at least 15 years old" IsVisible="{Binding TooYoung}"/>
```

I am binding the `Date` and `IsVisible` as I am using the pattern MVVM. So, if the user is not old enough the second label should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var difference = DateSelected.subtract(DateTime.Today);
if (difference.TotalDays <= 5475){
    //Trigger error event
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't you mean `difference.TotalDays <= 5475` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try bellow code:

```
    public bool TooYoung { get; set; }

    private DateTime _DateSelected;

    public DateTime DateSelected
    {
        get { return _DateSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_DateSelected.Equals(value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _DateSelected = value;

            // check someone is too young or not
            var age = CalculateAge(_DateSelected);
            TooYoung = age <= 15;
        }
    }

    private int CalculateAge(DateTime birthDay)
    {
        int years = DateTime.Now.Year - birthDay.Year;

        if ((birthDay.Month > DateTime.Now.Month) || (birthDay.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && birthDay.Day > DateTime.Now.Day))
            years--;

        return years;
    }
```